# Include file from node_modules to nyc

Tags: mocha.js, node-modules, istanbul, nyc

I want to use nyc to generate code-coverage. I am building some of my projects into node_modules to use them in other projects. When writing tests I want to test the files inside node_modules and therefore I want to include files from node_modules.

### Project-Example-Structure

```
1. foo (directory)
    1.1 bar (directory)
        1.1.1 node_modules (directory)
            1.1.1.1 someFile.js // I want to include this!
        1.1.2 foobar
            1.1.2.1 foobar.js // this file works
        1.1.3 .nycrc
```

### .nycrc

```
{
"reporter": [
    "html",
    "text"
],



"all": true,

"cwd": "../",

"report-dir": "./bar/test-run/coverage",
"include": [
    "./bar/**/foobar/*.js",
    "./bar/**/node_modules/*.js",
]
}
```

### Execute in terminal

```
nyc mocha
```

### Explanation

nyc uses the .nycrc. cwd: change-working-directory. I want to be able to include files of parent-directory. Sadly include seems not to be able to use "../".

Inside the include-flag I am specifying which files should be included:
"./bar/foobar/foobar.js" does somehow not work. 
But: "./bar/**/foobar/foobar.js" includes foorbar.js.

### Expected behaiviour

someFile.js should be included. foorbar.js should be included.

### Observed behaiviour

someFile.js is **not** included. foorbar.js **is** included.

### Environment

MacOS Sierra

nyc 11.8.0

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your config files with

```
{
"include": [
      "node_modules/**/<fileName>.js"
 ],
"excludeNodeModules": false
}
```